# C# OpenXML PowerPoint How to get Slide Duration

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, slide, duration

How can I get total slide duration time in PPTX file inculde effect?

```
using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"C:\powerpoint\sample.pptx", true))
        {
            // Get the presentation part of the document.
            PresentationPart presentationPart = doc.PresentationPart;
            // No presentation part? Something is wrong with the document.
            if (presentationPart == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("fileName");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(presentationPart.SlideParts.Count() + "count");
            // I want to get like this
            presentationPart.SlidePart.Duration();
        }
```

Comment: are you referring to the duration of time the transition between each slide takes?  Or the duration of any animation or embedded videos in the slide?  Can you elaborate more on what exact duration you need to find please?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I want to know the duration of time the duration each slide takes.Finally, I want to know entire duration of time. Because I developed WPF application embedded power point viewer. If slideshow ended, I want to catch.but I suppose it is impossible.

Comment: I can imagine a user would want to pause on a slide to think about the information?  If this is true, then it might be hard to determine using openxml.  If this is the case, I would suggest, you could put a timer in the WPF side and measure the duration from when the user opened the powerpoint to when they closed it.  However, If you need to determine the total amount of time the presentation takes to present to the user without pause, I think this can be determined with openxml.  Let me know what you intend.

Comment: It is assumed the slideshow without user's pause like a Degital Signage.
Do you know that how can I get the total amount of time? Thank you.

Comment: I understand.  I think I have a way and Ill post it later tonight.

Comment: That really helps. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

In order for a Presentation to play without pause, [you need to make the Presentation Self Running](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-self-running-presentation-3caf0cef-7cda-40f1-ab7a-f161a1a91d93).  Once you do this, the duration of each slide is stored as an attribute named Advance After Time (**advTm**).  The value is stored as text milliseconds in the **Transition** element.  The details can be [referenced here under the Transition Trigger heading near the bottom](http://officeopenxml.com/prSlide-transitions.php).

Example xml is shown here:

[image]

Note: there are two transitions - one under the **Choice** element and the other under the **Fallback** element.  You can ignore the one under Fallback because the **advTm** attribute will always be the same in both.

I wrote a method that will return the first **advTm** found for a **SlidePart**, otherwise it returns 0.

```
private string GetSlideDuration(SlidePart slidePart)
    {
        string returnDuration = "0";
        try
        {
            Slide slide1 = slidePart.Slide;

            var transitions = slide1.Descendants<Transition>(); 
            foreach (var transition in transitions)
            {
                if (transition.AdvanceAfterTime.HasValue)
                    return transition.AdvanceAfterTime;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }

        return returnDuration;

    }
```

I used this to write a simple WPF application that displays the total time of the Presentation.

[image]

The code for the wpf can be found [here](https://github.com/thomasbtatum/PowerPointDurationWPF).

**Update**

After more research, I've discovered that [transitions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.presentation.transition.duration) and [animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.presentation.commontimenode.duration.aspx) will add to the slide time.  Advance After Time duration discussed above does not cut these times short and must be accounted for also.  So I have updated the solution code at the github link above to take account of these.  A new screen shot for the slide times with breakdowns and total presentation time is here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detail post so much.
I ask you a question. the powerpoint file which has transition effect has "dur" attribute, doesn't it? I suppose I need to include the "dur" time if I measure the total time of the Presentation.

Comment: In addtion, I found that if the slide has animation object, the actual total duration is late.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: In your previous comments, you said there will be no user pause.  This implies you will need to make the presentations self running.  When you make the presentation self running, you dictate the times per slide.  For example if a slides' animation takes 50 seconds and you tell it to take 1 second, then the 1 second self running duration (advTm) will override the animation (dur)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you said, I assumed the application is no user pause. This is collect. I set powerpoint file to auto presentation mode. However Self running presentaion can include the object animation. and Powerpoint viewer wait the object animation time.

if advTm is 3 seconds, dureation is 1 seconds, object animation is 2 second, this slide's total transition time is 6 seconde and if there is multipe object animation which is serial, I need add multiple animation time.

I need calculate all of this.

Comment: ok - I will update the solution soon to reflect transition times and animation times.  These are similar to pull out of the xml like 'advTm'

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm waiting for your post.

Comment: please check the new solution for a better time calculation.

Comment: Thank you for you update. I tried your sample. Almost do fine, but there is two cases which are not doing fine.

First, if I add the animation to textbox, doing fine. If I add the animation to the picture, I get the twice animation time.

Second, if the animation is sequential , doing fine, but if  the animation is simultaneous not correct.

 Is there a solution? In addtion, I found out I can set delay time of animation. Can I get the delay time? the sample powerpoint file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7llMlC6w-OncnRjM3VJSFZKWmM/view)

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Hi, very late to join the party but is there a way to get the transition times from all of the animations of each slide? The code provided gets the time after which the first transition happens (although I don't quite how that adds up from the xml...). I can't however find out the time of all the animations in one slide if there are multiple.

Comment: Hi @Oliver, I encourage you to ask a new question on Stack Overflow.  It will get addressed and answered.  Feel free to at me in the comments of your question if no answer comes.  However you will find that in developing a thoughtful question, you often find the solution or a work around.