# Howto get total duration of a Powerpoint file

Tags: delphi, powerpoint, duration

I need to have the functionality in my delphi application to get the total duration time of a given Powerpoint-File (pptx format).

Anybody who can get me going?

Thanks a lot already in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found it!
this is what I have, and it seems to work.

```
function GetPPTDurationSec(pPPTFileName: String): Integer;
var
    oPPTApp: OleVariant;
    oPPTPresenation: OleVariant;
    iX, iTotalSlides, iSlideTime, iTotalTime: Integer;
begin
    Try
        Result := 0;
        oPPTApp := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
        oPPTPresenation := oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(pPPTFileName, True, True, False);
        iTotalSlides := oPPTPresenation.Slides.Count;
        iTotalTime := 0;
        for iX := 1 to iTotalSlides do
        begin
            iSlideTime := oPPTPresenation.Slides.Item(iX).SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime;
            iTotalTime := iTotalTime + iSlideTime;
        end;
        oPPTPresenation.Close;
        oPPTApp.Quit;
        Result := iTotalTime;
      Except
          Result := 0;
      End;
end;
```

Comment: Be aware that you need to have PowerPoint installed for this to work.

Comment: While I don't have any expirience of working with PowerPoint through OLE I doubt that your code will return you correct result. Why? The advance time is the time that it takes for slide to advance to the next one after the last animation and not since the slide was shown. So if for instance on a specific slide you have 5 objects which are shown in series with 5 second intervals and the AdvanceTime of the slide is also 5 seconds your code will return 5 while in reality the slide would be shown for 30 second (5x5 seconds for showing five objects and another 5 seconds for slide AdvanceTime)

Comment: So in order for you to get tghe correct time that certain slide show will be shown you need to combine AdvanceTime for every animation plus AdvanceTime of the specific slide.

Comment: @Olivier - Thanks for feedback. that is indeed true.
I don't think there is another way to do it I suppose?
It would be great if there is a way to get the data from the PPT-file, even if Powerpoint is not installed on the pc

Comment: @SilverWarrior - You are probably right. Maybe I can try to find the correct objects to get the AdvanceTime for every animation too.

Comment: In theory you can extract the XML files inside the .pptx (which is actually a zip archive) and parse them, but that's some work.

Comment: @Olivier: I have extracted the pptx-file and when I check for example the slide1.xml, I can find the 'advTm' value, which is the same as my 'oPPTPresenation.Slides.Item(iX).SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime' in my code.
But I also want the Transition duration from the xml-file, but I can't find this value.
any idea what entry in the xml-file this is?

Comment: No idea but you may find some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225050/c-sharp-openxml-powerpoint-how-to-get-slide-duration).

Comment: @Olivier: Thanks so far. I will take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks everybody for you help so far.

Comment: @Olivier: I checked you link about the Open XML approach.
I thinks will go that way.
I already created a small console app in C# which calculates the total duration using the code I found in the link you provided.
Thanks all for your help and support!

Answer (score 0):

one simpler solution (hack) without using ole and without installing powerpoint:

change the pptx extension to .zip (powerpoint files are a bunch of files compressed under the ppts extension) and read all the info you want from the file  ppt/PRESENTATION.xml

done.